# Колонки вылазят за контейнер, display: grid

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, css-grid

Экспериментирую с `display: grid`, хочу сделать 3 колонки с промежутком между ними по 20 пикселей. Задаю им процентную ширину 33.33% и в итоге проблема — колонки вылазят за контейнер. Как это исправить?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33.33%);
  border: 1px solid;
}

.grid__column {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class=grid>
  <div class=grid__column>Column text #1</div>
  <div class=grid__column>Column text #2</div>
  <div class=grid__column>Column text #3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: так работает - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/94bbp8eg/

Comment: не очень хорошо работает, в конце есть еще один gap.

Comment: как я понял с % в данном случае grid не корректно работает

Comment: С   grid-gap: 1%;  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 32.66%); вроде неплохо отработал

Comment: @DmitryKulevich в процентах задавать gap как-то не очень хочется.

Comment: @soledar10 В вашем примере, чтобы не было разрыва в конце, надо высчитывать проценты от grid-gap: 20px-(20*33.33%) = 13.34. Код тогда будет выглядеть как grid-template-columns:  repeat(3, calc(33.33% - 13.34px )); - но это все же костыль по сравнению с возможностями Grid Layout.

Comment: @labris - Спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы колонки не "вылазили" за контейнер, надо корректно использовать свойство `grid-template-columns` и все возможности Grid Layout.

Строку

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33.33%);
```

Надо заменить на:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/ma5t66df/

P.S. Таким образом легко, к примеру, сделать среднюю колонку в 2 раза шире боковых:

```
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо процентов используйте `fr`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 3, 3fr);
  border: 1px solid;
}

.grid__column {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class=grid>
  <div class=grid__column>Column text #1</div>
  <div class=grid__column>Column text #2</div>
  <div class=grid__column>Column text #3</div>
</div>
```